# Ignite's off-heap storage's working and advantages over heap storage

Tags: java, heap-memory, ignite, off-heap

I understand off-heap storage helps in avoiding long GC pauses, but I want to know how java serializes objects while storing on heap and how ignite serializes while storing off-heap?, like GC is run to free up space, what happens when off-heap is used to free up space and how that compares with GC? How does off-heap fares against heap storage?

We are trying a POC to evaluate ignite and hazelcast, ignite offers off-heap storage, so want to understand the details of it to come to a conclusion..

Comment: I’m not sure you should use heap/off-heap to decide which to use! (Hazelcast also offers off-heap storage, though only in their enterprise version.) Why not concentrate on features and performance?

Comment: When it comes to features both implement Jcache JSR107 so more on they are same, except that ignite supports SQL like querying and can perform distributed joins and in terms of performance ignite has edge over hazelcast. Is there anything else which you think can be useful to decide which one to go with?

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't serialize data which is stored on-heap. The whole idea of serialization is about taking away objects from heap to other medium, such as off-heap. So it's just stored.

Ignite implements fast serialization using Binary Objects, Externalizable and Binarylizable interfaces.

Ignite does not need to GC its off-heap since it explicitly keeps tracks of all key-value pairs. When something is deleted the memory is available for use immediately (GC is only really needed for graph systems, not key-value and neither SQL).

However, things might be somewhat different for recently introduced transactional SQL with its vacuum procedure.

Comment: So this serialization will slow down the performance? Also when you say it keeps track of all key value pairs, does that mean additional overhead so it is coming at a cost of memory?

Comment: Does this also mean that one has to choose from slight slow response or deal with long GC pauses while making a decision of heap or off-heap storage?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, it has given me some clarity!

Comment: Yes, there is a certain trade-off here. However when you start to rebalance data or send over to other nodes, you will have to serialize anyway, even if using on-heap solution